# Chrome v23 didn't support viewport scale or viewport meta tag?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, css, viewport

I made a HTML5 Webapp and I want it auto scaled by window size on PC (not mobile).
so I add it in css:

```
@-ms-viewport { width: 1024px; }
@-webkit-viewport { width: 1024px; }
@-moz-viewport { width: 1024px; }
@-o-viewport { width: 1024px; }
@viewport { width: 1024px; }
```

In IE10(Win8), It OK, if window is resized smaller, everything in html is smaller. the html has scaled down.

but In Chrome v23, if window is resized smaller, everything in html is NOT scaled at all.Chrome v23 didn't support viewport scale?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [`@viewport` is not yet implemented in Chrome](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95959).  As far as I'm aware, the `viewport` meta tag has only ever been implemented in mobile browsers, not desktop ones.

Comment: What a pity, it seems that only IE10 already implemented it on desktop browsers. Is there any chrome nightly build version implemented it now?

Comment: @Jove I don't think so. While the [source](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/css/CSSPropertyNames.in)  indicates there is a ENABLE_CSS_DEVICE_ADAPTATION flag for it, I don't see it enabled in any builds yet. And they probably don't want to release a -webkit prefixed version, so this will take time.

Comment: [This post](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155477) says it can be enabled via `--enable-experimental-webkit-features` (through chrome://flags) and `--enable-viewport` (through parameter). I confirmed Chrome Canary has at least a parser for `@viewport`, unprefixed.